# Is there a way to prevent boost.log from leaking memory?

Tags: c++, boost-log

I have created a very simple test program based off the boost.log tutorial:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

#define LOG_TRACE BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace)
#define LOG_DEBUG BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug)
#define LOG_INFO BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info)
#define LOG_WARN BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning)
#define LOG_ERR BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error)
#define LOG_FATAL BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal)

int
main(int argc,
     const char *argv[])
{
  LOG_TRACE << "A trace severity message";
  LOG_DEBUG << "A debug severity message";
  LOG_INFO << "An informational severity message";
  LOG_WARN << "A warning severity message";
  LOG_ERR << "An error severity message";
  LOG_FATAL << "A fatal severity message";
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this under valgrind, it produces 7 loss records, which is consistent with the results that I see in more complex programs using boost.log.  Does anybody know of any way to eliminate these leaks, or do I just need to suppress them?

Comment: did u find out what was the issue?

Comment: No info yet, currently investigating other logging solutions as well.

Comment: Any news or did you give up?...

Comment: If this wasn't a very old question I'd ask you to add your valgrind output.